# Which data can be used from javascript (webpage) in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile, cross-browser

I spent some time try to figure out which and what `iOS` user's data can be used from `javascript` (web app or website) **without any additional permissions** (location/camera/contact list etc) but didn't come out with a proper answer.

Does anyone help?

Thanks in advance!